# Amazon Workspaces on ubuntu: copy / paste issue between multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon workspaces on a Linux client: ubuntu.

The Amazon workspaces are Windows 10.

My issue is that I cannot copy / past anything across multiple monitors. I can copy and paste between the physical machine and the amazon workspaces virtual machine, but I cannot copy/paste any info from my first monitor to my secondary monitor while on the workspace session. I checked to be sure copy and paste was working on my physical Linux machine and it is working just fine. I have been googling solutions but have not had much luck.

Anything helps!